# Evolutionary advantage of the nutrient played by the chicken

Tags: evolution, zoology

What is the evolutionary advantage of the chicken throwing out so much nutrient ovulating all the time?

Is there a clear advantage to this? Chickens ovulate all the time for the same reason human females do, when the egg is not fertilized it is discarded, in the case of the hen it lays an egg, in the human case menstruation occurs. This is due to the rhythm of reproduction of each species, if the egg is fertilized, it is an advantage that it can fertilize all the time.

Comment: First, most chickens will not naturally lay an egg every day. (I raised hundreds - yes, hundreds - of chickens.) It varies, with some breeds (selected over many decades, some hundreds of years) being "heavy layers" and others absolutely not. Also, artificial light and heat is needed to produce eggs year round. If there are roosters around, trust me, almost all (if not all) of the eggs will be fertilized. I used to hatch out my own chicks from fresh eggs collected in no particular manner. I never had a dud. Today's commercial and farm chickens are not the "originals".

Comment: @anongoodnurse in the end is it useful to lay a lot of eggs by artificial selection, in short?

Comment: Be careful you aren't doing something akin to asking what the evolutionary advantage of a seedless orange or grocery store banana is.

Comment: It is useful *to humans selling and buying them* for chickens to be forced to lay eggs every day, yes. Does that take a toll on chickens' lives? Yes, a great toll. My chickens did not lay eggs every day, and were not killed when production decreased. In return for having been selectively bred for egg laying, and doing so for me, I gave them a good life. I did not force them to lay eggs in any way.

Comment: @DKNguyen but seedless fruit only exists transgenic, no?

Comment: @Behemooth Not transgenic. Seedless fruits are a naturally occurring mutation that would have otherwise died out but was found and artificially propagated. Think about it...what organism would you even get a seedless gene from to insert it into something to begin with?